# Is there a spell or effect that will summon a living humanoid to you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

My party is trying to retrieve an old friend (female Sun Elf Cleric, if it's relevant) from a nonmagical prison facility.  The hope is that a spellcaster from **outside** the prison will be able to cast a spell to pull her out of prison, even if they don't know exactly what cell she is in.

She isn't in any imminent danger, so there's no time frame and the requisite spell/effect could feasibly be at any level.

Is there a spell (or other magical effect) that can do this?

Comment: Is it a possible solution when a wizard first teleports into a prison, and then teleports out with the friend? Or is it obligatory to do that in a single spell?

Comment: @enkryptor speaking as the DM, the prison is actually a critical late-game location and I'd prefer to provide a tool to the PCs that doesn't let them directly inside of it.

Comment: @Robert if you're the GM, why do you ask this question? It should be up to the players how to free her from the prison. Let your players invent their own method.

Comment: @enkryptor Robert says the requisite spell or effect could be any level. So, yes. Though the Wish spell is a bit of a catch all solution, I admit that. I just meant that we have confirmation that level is not a factor here and we can use any option that meets the need.

Comment: What is keeping the Cleric in the prison?  You mention that the prison is non-magical so it would seem the Cleric could just cast Freedom of Movement and spend 5ft of movement to bust out of jail.  At even higher levels, imprisonment in a non-magical prison seems increasingly unlikely (Planar Ally, Etherealness, Plane Shift, etc).

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Freedom of Movement doesn't allow you to go through walls, and you need a material component to cast it

Comment: @enkryptor "a leather strap, bound around the arm or a similar appendage" is not exactly hard to come by, even in jail.  And a non-magical prison is almost definitionally a non-magical restraint.  Regardless, the OP has given no indication as to why escape for the target is non-trivial, which presumably would inform what kinds of magic would work for the players.

Answer (score 5):

A low(ish)-level solution:

### Use Sending spell to reveal her whereabouts

Using the Sending spell you can send her a message and receive an answer. You can ask, if there was a window and what did she see in the window. You also should ask if she was restrained somehow or chained to a wall.

### Pass her a spell scroll of Gaseous Form

From the DMG, page 139:

> A scroll is a consumable magic item. Whatever the
> nature of the magic contained in a scroll, unleashing
> that magic requires using an action to read the scroll.
> When its magic has been invoked, the scroll can't be
> used again. Its words fade, or it crumbles into dust.
> Any creature that can understand a written language
> can read the arcane script on a scroll and attempt to
> activate it

A familiar (or a trained animal) can pass the scroll through a barred window. Using the scroll the cleric can cast the Gaseous Form spell (PHB page 244):

> **Casting Time:** 1 action
> **Duration:** Concentration, up to 1 hour
>
> You transform a willing creature you touch, along with everything it's wearing and carrying, into a misty cloud for the duration.
>
> ...
>
> The target can pass through small holes, narrow openings, and even mere cracks, though it treats liquids as though they were solid surfaces.

Answer (score 4):

#### Depending upon the level of magic your party has access to, here's a method.

Luck Blade (SRD 5.1 pg. 229/DMG p. 179) or Ring of Three Wishes (SRD 5.1 pg. 238/DMG p. 193).
Both have wishes on them.

Procedure:
Make a wish that the elf cleric be brought to / appear next to your exact location.  This is within the bounds of the strength of a wish spell.  It replicates the effects of a 7th level teleport spell on her, and adds a bit since you don't know precisely where she is.

#### Alternate Method

Tools: Scrying spell (5th level, SRD p. 176/PHB p. 273) and two Dimension Door spells (4th level, SRD p. 135/PHB p. 233).
Procedure:

1. Scry to find her.
2. Get within 500' of her location. (the range of DD).
3. DD in. (Using her as the location)
4. DD out. (Using another party member as the target location)

   - Use a *ring of spell storing* if need be to be able to cast any of the above spells, or use scrolls.
5. Accept her sweet embrace and her exclamation of "You're my hero!"

Caveat: if her location is greater than 500 feet from the outside of the prison, this won't work unless you're able to cast a series of DD spells on the way in and cast the same number of DD spells on the way out.  This begins to take the solution to the *captive princess problem* well beyond the original to effect her escape by summoning.  (thanks to @markovchain for that point).

Since you did not make the range clear, the alternate solution was offered for the case of her cell being 500' or less from the outside of the prison.

Comment: It's still viable at greater multiples of 500'. They just have to DD multiple times.

Comment: @markovchain I folded in your point on chaining DD spells together.

Answer (score 2):

It's expensive and high level but if he ran across a spell scroll with the *gate spell* on it - it'd be fairly simple.

## Gate

- Page: 244 Players Handbook
- Conjuration
- Level: 9
- Casting time: 1 Action
- Range: 60 feet
- Components: V, S, M (a diamond worth at least 5,000 gp)
- Duration: Concentration, up to 1 minute

When you cast this spell, you can speak the name of a specific creature (a pseudonym, title, or nickname doesn’t work). If that creature is on a plane other than the one you are on, the portal opens in the named creature’s immediate vicinity and **draws the creature through it to the nearest unoccupied space on your side of the portal**. You gain no special power over the creature, and it is free to act as the Dm deems appropriate. It might leave, attack you, or help you.

Comment: You might want to mention " If that creature is on a plane other than the one you are on"

Comment: Good Catch! I wouldn't be a stickler about a 9th level spell in my games but to be totally true to the rules you might combine it with the **Plane Shift** spell.

Comment: This *doesn't* work if she's on the same plane.  @nontoxicjon I recommend you edit the bit about *plane shift* into your answer.

Comment: A number of easier tricks can remove you from the plane of the target, such as getting into a bag of holding or rope trick.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the already mentioned methods of teleport in and out, and plane shifting, casting gate, and plane shifting back (2x 7th level spells an a 9th level spell), I am not aware of any spells or items that can summon someone to you.

You could pass them a spell scroll (as mentioned elsewhere) to help them escape (invisibility, passwall, meld with stone, gaseous form, teleportation, etc...), or try to get them an item that allows them to cast teleportation.  Neither of these feel like the best solution to the problem you are presenting.

My suggestion would be to homebrew a pair of sending stones like Matt Mercer used in Critical Role.  These aren't the DMG stones, which is literally a pair of 1/day stone walkie-talkeies.  Mercer made these effectively a limited teleportation object: You can activate either stone to teleport yourself to the other stone.  Sending a person rather than a message.

If you make an item like this (maybe a damaged one that only has 1d3 charges, if you feel this is too broken), then they can figure how to get this stone to the prisoner, and how to inform the prisoner of how to use it to escape.

This has the added bonus of not completely solving your players problem for them.  You are just changing it from *how to I break someone out of this prison* to *how to I get this stone to the right person in that prison*.  If you just present them a *scroll of summoning people by name*, then they're going to feel cheated.  You gave them a problem to solve, then solved it for them.

---

If I were to write out the block for the stones, here's how I would do it:

> ***Sending Stones***
>
> *Wonderous Item, Uncommon*
>
> The runes on these two ornately carved stones pulse back and forth, perfectly opposite of each other.  When the stones are separated by more than 1 mile, a user can activate one and be instantly teleported to any open space within 5 feet of the other stone.  The activated stone travels with the user.
>
> If there is no unoccupied space within 5 feet of the other stone, the activation fails.

It's a nice item, but hardly game breaking, since you have to get the stone into place before teleportation there.  Plus since it's only a single person teleport, your PCs won't be using it for mass transit either.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what nontoxicjon already said I would suggest a combination of:

preparation: Be a wizard with *scrying(level 5)*, *teleport(level 7)* and *teleportation circle*(level 5) spells. Have a known teleportation sigil (a temple, a guild you belong to, or other important place. The spell itself says that you immediately know 2 destinations when obtaining it, determined by gm. I would assume at least one of those is NOT part of the prison.)

1. *Scrying* (spell, targeting the friend you want to rescue. Try until you succeed, afterwards you can just target the prison cell itself and succeed automatically, because you can always scry places that you have seen before.)
2. Investigate the cell plenty of times. As you said, no timeframe.
3. *Teleport* (spell) to the location. You may have obtained the 'seen casually' option of teleport, or maybe even better, due to *scrying*. Or if DM allows you to teleport while having scrying up(I don't see why not), you can have the 'very familiar' option in the bank.
4. Use *teleportation circle* to teleport to your temple/guildhall/whathaveyou.
5. Party hard.

Caveats:

- The teleport spell can get you to a false destination or even inflict
  damage.
- Teleportation circle casting time is 1 minute. It may get rough if the guards are aware of your shenanigans. This can be countered by making enough scrying castings to note how often guards pass the cell.

Answer (score 0):

### Etherealness

It's not "summoning", but you can conceivably free your friend using a **single spell** if you have level 8 spell slots. Cast [etherealness](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/etherealness) on yourself using your level 7 slot. A nonmagical prison facility should have no guardians or traps that can affect you in this state. (If there are supernatural guardian monsters, like a *shadow mastiff*, you need to be more careful.)

You now have 8 hours to invisibly walk through the prison, including any walls, to find your friend's cell. Once there, dismiss the spell, and cast it again using your level 8 slot, targeting yourself and your friend. Walk out together.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the catch-all spell "Wish", there is no published *single* spell, to my knowledge of any edition, that can teleport a named distant creature on the same plane currently at a location unknown to you, to you.  There are fairly good reasons for the lack of such a spell, namely that it would very frequently negate the need for adventuring at all!  Why go through the BBEG's tower of fiends when you can summon him to you instead!  Even assuming it would require a *willing* target, it would still negate a number of other quests, such as locating a reclusive master, or, as you have here, rescuing a prisoner.

The other answers offer suggestions for other spells that will be useful in jailbreaking your target.  That's great!  There are *lots* of magical means to perform a jailbreak, as there should be!  But there just isn't a single spell (again, aside from "Wish") that can do it quite so easily, and very few options that won't require you or an agent to be there in person to enact the jailbreak, putting you in at least a little risk.  And honestly, I think that's fine... some things require a bit more creativity and risk, and that's the fun of the game!